# curl bad request 400 при обращении к API

Tags: php

Делаю обращение к API

```
$this->curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://imdb-api.com/en/API/$API/$this->API_KEY/$data",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
        ));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($this->curl));
```

Если в переменную `$data` приходит одно слово, то все работает, если 2 слова и более, например "lost in space" то `curl_exec($this->curl)` возвращает это:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Интересно то, что если я пытаюсь открыть через браузер ссылку на API (ту что я формирую здесь `CURLOPT_URL => "https://imdb-api.com/en/API/$API/$this->API_KEY/$data"`), то в браузере все ОК.
Вот как выглядит сформированный УРЛ, который не работает на сервере `https://imdb-api.com/en/API/SearchMovie/k_xvb2gmlk/Lost in space`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В URL не может быть пробелов, поэтому они должны быть заменены на сочетание `%20`.

Comment: спасибо! Помогло. Но теперь столкнулся с другой проблемой. В $data еще может прийти строка на кирилице. В таком случае ситуация возникает похожая как и с пробелами. Пробовал использовать urlencode, но к сожалению не помогло

Comment: Странно, что urlencode не помог, ведь он именно предназначен именно для экранирования UTF-8 строк в вид, пригодный для использования в URL. Попробуйте сначала убедиться, что у вас исходная строка в кодировке UTF-8. Если это не так - преобразуйте строку перед urlencode в UTF-8.